# Are pepper plants worth trying to save after root rot?

Tags: containers, peppers

I am very much a newbie gardener.  I found out the hard way that I was definitely over watering my pepper seedlings, which led to root rot and leaves falling off, as well as the main stem (the tip of it) looking dry.  I have recently transferred the plants into new soil, and although they look healthy, I have no idea if the main stem will repair itself and keep growing/producing leaves, or if the harm has been done and there is no chance for survival.

Comment: I'm eager to see if someone has an answer but if I were you in the mean time I'd start some new seedlings to be on the safe side. If they all come out fine then you can give some away.

Comment: Please post a photo or two so we can assess the plants' condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [save pepper seedlings from root rot](http://www.gardenguides.com/100937-root-rot-peppers.html) if you catch it early on. Your plants were severely affected and most likely won't make it. I agree with @OrganicLawnDIY, start some new ones to stay on the safe side. If any of the diseased plants survive, they won't have the vigor of healthy seedlings. It is tricky to save plants from root rot, because once you can see the effects it is generally too late. I have saved an aloe vera from root rot, so I know it can be possible.